# jQuery browser height is not accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to determine the actual height of the browser in relationship to the screen height in jQuery. For some reason, the readings are far from accurate and I'd like to know why.

Basically the issue I'm having is that

1. The `window.innerHeight` and `window.outerHeight` are always exactly the same even though the tabs bar is being shown and there is an obvious (visual) difference between the 2...
2. Each of the readings above are **always** smaller than `screen.height` and `screen.availHeight`. I was under the impression that this should not be the case if the browser is maximized vs full screen vs sized vs minimized?

My requirement is to change the class of an element on the `window.scroll` event when that element reaches the top of the browser viewport. However, I am also mandated to change to a different class if the browser window is sized instead of maximized or full screen.

Here's the code that performs this operation however, like I mentioned above, the "maximized" if statement is never true... why?

```
function SetFloatingDivCheck(ContainerName, StartingClassName, FixedClassNameSized, FixedClassNameMaximized) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ElemY = $('#' + ContainerName).offset().top - parseFloat($('#' + ContainerName).css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var YPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (YPosition >= ElemY) {
            $('#' + ContainerName).removeClass(StartingClassName);
            //the following alert/debug shows this: 1050, 949, 949, 1010 when fired.
            //alert("screen.height = " + screen.height.toString() + "\nwindow.innerHeight = " + window.innerHeight.toString() + "\nwindow.outerHeight = " + window.innerHeight.toString() + "\n screen.availHeight = " + screen.availHeight.toString());

            if (screen.height == window.outerHeight || screen.availHeight == window.outerHeight)
            {

                $('#' + ContainerName).addClass(FixedClassNameMaximized);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#' + ContainerName).addClass(FixedClassNameSized);
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#' + ContainerName).removeClass(FixedClassNameSized);
            $('#' + ContainerName).removeClass(FixedClassNameMaximized);
            $('#' + ContainerName).addClass(StartingClassName);
        }
    });

});
}
```

Comment: Don’t know what you mean in your second point, do you expect a maximized/fullscreen browser window to be bigger than the actual screen dimensions …?

Comment: _“My requirement is to change the class of an element on the window.scroll event when that element reaches the top of the screen”_ – that “requirement” makes little sense, if my browser window _itself_ does not even touch the top border of the screen.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I just tried `window.innerHeight` and `window.outerHeight` in Google Chrome console and they were both different.

Comment: @CBroe no, if you look at the code, i expect them to be equal. And for the screen part you're right that was badly written... see edited version of the question.

Comment: @JamieBarker strangely... Chrome... :( i get 1050, 949, 949, 1010 ...

Comment: I am on version `42.0.2311.90 m`, how about you?

Comment: If the "tabs bar" is the part of the browser at the top, that doesn't make a difference between `innerHeight` and `outerHeight`, the difference is in borders and margin etc. `screen` is the actual screen, regardless of browser size.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv Your testing is bugged. Your alert states `window.outerHeight = " + window.innerHeight.toString()`. See the problem? ;)

Comment: i am on version `41.0.2272.101` ... though i doubt that that should make a difference... ?? -- @adeneo please look at the definition of outer vs inner height on the jquery website. Outer includes the browser's tabs and menu bars...

Comment: @JamieBarker oh well crud! THANK YOU! :D Please place that as your answer to my problem for the points. somehow I had made the same mistake in my IF statement on my local code and this now works perfectly. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I doubt the window would ever include browser chrome ?

Comment: Also note that you're not using jQuery, but the native methods. jQuery's `outerHeight` is not applicable on the window or document

Comment: @adeneo please make a search, and/or test out my code using JamieBarker's fix. The outerHeight and screen.height are <strong>equal</strong> when maximized so yes... it does include the tabs and the menu bar for the browser in its readings.

Comment: @adeneo just try `window.outerHeight` in your console.

Comment: In my browser `screen.height - window.outerHeight` gives me `40`, which is the height of my browser chrome. There's no way the window would include the browser chrome

Comment: @adeneo What on earth is your definition of "_browser chrome_"?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv Answer below.

Comment: The borders of a Web browser window, which include the window frames, menus, toolbars tabs etc. The window is the place where the webpage is viewed, the screen is the entire screen, the chrome is the browser UI stuff. Maximizing a browser means it takes up the entire screen, but with chrome visible. Setting a browser to "fullscreen" generally removes the chrome.

Comment: @adeneo `window.outerHeight` is height **including** the _chrome_ , `window.innerHeight` is height **excluding** the _chrome_. The confusion has come from the [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) conversation above it. You will be getting 40 in your calculation because that will be how high your windows task-bar is (start menu, system tray, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testing is bugged. Your alert states `window.outerHeight = " + window.innerHeight.toString()`